# Turning a 1D array and a variable into a new 2D array

Tags: arrays, typescript

Im new to programming and Im struggling with arrays in typescript.
I have the following variables:

```
let nameList: string[] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    let postId: number = 1;
```

My goal is to create a new 2D array:
 `let newList: (string | number)[][] = [];`

where

```
newlist = [
      [a,1],
      [b,1],
      [c,1],
      [d,1]
    ]
```

I've tried:

```
for (let i: number = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
      newList[i][0].push(userList[i]);
      newList[i][1].push(insertID);
    }
```

Also

```
for (let i: number = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
      newList[i][0] = userList[i];
      newList[i][1] = insertID;
    }
```

Can someone help me with this?
Much apprerciated!

Comment: Try something like `const newList: Array<[string, number]> = nameList.map(value => [value, postId]);`; I also changed your type a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const new2dArray: [string, number][] = nameList.map((name) => [name, postId]);`